# Sorl-Thumbnail static image in default

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I use Sorl-Thumbnail in my django-project. I have a situation, when I havent got an image and I need to show `no_image.png`.
This code works:

```
{% thumbnail car.default_picture.image|default:"http://example.com/img/no_image.png" "240x180" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

But I want to use `{% static "img/no_image.png" %}` in default. I have an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Syntax error. Expected: ``thumbnail source geometry [key1=val1 key2=val2...] as var`
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: @MatheusJardimB yes, here is an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found this alternative too:

```
{% thumbnail product.logo "200x200" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% empty %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/default.gif' %}" width="200" height="200">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if car.default_picture.image %}
thumbnail
{% else %}
{% static "img/no_image.png" %}
{% endif %}
```

It works for me